# Java ExecutorService shutdownNow not interrupting

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, shutdown

I'm having issues shutting down executor service in my password cracker assignment.
I'm aware that `shutdownNoW()` does not have any guarantee and only tries its best by sending interruption to all threads. I have tried putting `Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()` here and there but something is still missing. I have checked and it stops checking new possibilities and CPU performance drops suddenly as well but the app still continues to run.
What am I missing?

```
public void decrypt() {
    setStartTime();
    generateTasks();
    for (Callable<String> task : tasks) {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(task);
        futureList.add(future);
    }
    for (Future<String> future : futureList) {
        try {
            if (future.get() != null) {
                executor.shutdownNow();
                decryptedPassword = future.get();
                runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                printResult();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void generateTasks() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxPasswordLength; i++) {
        for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) {
            tasks.add(new GuessGroup(ch, i, possibleChars, encryptedPassword));
        }
    }
}
```

My GuessGroup class implementing Callable:

```
@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++) {
        String result = recursiveCrack("", i);
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        else if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public String recursiveCrack(String stem, int length) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        return null;
    }
    if (length == 0) {
        if (hashCalc.hash(prefix + stem).equals(encryptedPassword)) {
            String result = prefix + stem;
            return result;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (char ch : possibleChars) {
            String result = recursiveCrack(stem + ch, length - 1);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Take a thread dump and see which threads are still running or waiting on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it was a very silly one...
I added a `break` into the for loop which iterated through the Future list after the `shutdownNow` request and it fixed it.

```
for (Future<String> future : futureList) {
    try {
        if (future.get() != null) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
            decryptedPassword = future.get();
            runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            printResult();
            break;              // this was missing...
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All the threads were down already and only main was still running.